# How to manage a pool via a RESTful interface

Tags: rest, api, methods, restful-architecture, pool

As I am not sure I stated the question very well originally, I am restating it to see if there is a better response.

I have a problem with how best to manage a specific kind collection with a RESTful API. To help illustrate the issue I have I will use an simple artificial example. Lets call it the 'Raffle Ticket Selector'. For this question I am only interested in how to perform one function.

1. I have a collection of unpurchased raffle tickets (*raffleTickets*). Each with a unique Raffle Number along with other information.
2. I need to be able to take an identified number of tickets (numTickets) from the raffleTickets collection without uniquely selecting them. The collection itself has a mechanism for random selection.
3. The result is that I am returned 5 unique tickets from the collection and the size of the collection is decreased by 5 as the 5 returned have been removed.

The quesition is, how do I do it in a RESTfull way?
I intuatively want to do ***METHOD*** .../raffelTickets?numTickets=5 but struggle with which HTTP Method to use

In answering; you are not allowed to suggest that I just PATCH/PUT a status change to effect a removal by marking them taken. It must result an actual change in the cardanality of the collection.

***Note:*** Calling the method twice will return a different result set every time and will always alter the collection on which it is performed (unless it is empty!)

So what method should I use? PUT? POST? DELETE? PATCH?  Identpotent restrictions would seem to only leave me with POST and PATCH neither of which feels ideal to me. Or perhaps there is another way of providing the overall behavior that is considered the correct approach.

I am really interested to know what is best practice and understand why.

Cheers

---

Original Post on which the first response was based:

I have a pool of a given item which is to be managed with a RESTful API. Now adding items to the pool is not an issue but how to I take items from the pool? Is it also a POST or is it a DELETE? 
Lets say it is a pool of random numbers and I want to retrieve a variable number of items in a single method call.
I have two scenarios:

1. I am not checking them out as once taken they will not be returned to the pool.
2. I only want to check them out and they effectively remain part of the pool but have a status altered to 'inUse'

The important thing in each case is I do not care which items I get, I just want N of them.

What is considered the RESTful way performing each of the two actions on the pool? I have an opinion on the second option but I dither on the former so I am interested in your thoughts for both so I better understand the thought pattern

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood well your question. It will mostly depend on the way you developed the API side of your REST communication.

In a generic solution, you would use DELETE to take items out of a list. However, if you just want to PARTIALY update the items, you could use PATCH instead of POST or PUT.

Give this a look: http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/

Comment: I guess my question was that I think of a DELETE as being on a resource level so DELETE poolOfResources/{resourceID} and that is fine but I do not want to do that. I do not care which resource I get just give me N of them. And if I do DELETE on the pool (the collection) then am I not deleting the collection. 

Additionally if I perform a DELETE on the collection and make it give me N pool members and then repeat it I will not get the same result and I believe REST demands that DELETE be idempotent.

Comment: @DarylORegan, so, if you do a DELETE on the poolOfResources, you want to get N resource IDs (random) and want to make sure those N resources are marked as "deleted", so you don't get them again, later. Is that what you mean? That would depend very much on the way you code your GET action. 

Say, GET poolOfResources would return N resources and mark the N resources as, say, "deleted", or flag them as "done" or something.

Are we on the same page?

Comment: By the way, this is an interesting case/question.

Comment: Hi Daniel, 
To make it clear I have restated the question above with a tangible (I hope) example and removed one of the cases that may help focus. GET being both idempotent and safe is suspect as well I would say